# How to optimise chained operations geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm quite new with geometry nodes and something that I find sometimes annoying is chaining nodes.

In this examples, I want to exclude specific instances based on their indexes, so I have to create three Compare nodes and multiple them two by two.

I had another project where I was separating RGB colors, doing some math and adding them by having 2 Add nodes. (adding R+G, then adding the result with B)

Is there a way to multiple any amount of nodes together? 
Some sort of "plug as many input as you want" (like we have for the Join geometry node).

[image: Geometry nodes examples]

Comment: unfortunately not yet. But of course you can write your own custom node trees to reuse them. But this would have a specific number of inputs (as many as you gave them) of course. And by the way, instead of multiplying - you can use boolean math - node -> And ;)